# Cannot run pod command to add OpenSSL

Tags: xcode, macos, openssl, cocoapods

I am running on a Mac with OSX 10.8.x (Mountain Lion). I have inherited an XCode project (XCode 5) that I need to update with OpenSSL. This project is actually a workspace that uses cocoapods. I thought it would be easy to add OpenSSL as a new pod, so I found this:https://github.com/krzak/OpenSSL which says to type this command:

```
pod 'OpenSSL', :podspec => 'https://raw.github.com/krzak/OpenSSL/master/OpenSSL.podspec'
```

So, I went to terminal and did a CD into the root folder of the project, where the xcworkspace file is located. There I see a main folder for my project (call it MyProject) and another folder called Pods. I looked inside the Pods folder and I see a bunch of folders for various Pods (RESTKit, SOCKkit, etc). Each of these folders has its own podspec file. Anyway, I make sure I am CD-ed into the Pods folder, and then I run the command above. I get this response in terminal:

```
-bash: https://raw.github.com/krzak/OpenSSL/master/OpenSSL.podspec: No such file or directory
```

When I run 'which pod' I get /usr/bin/pod so I know that the pod command is installed. And I also know that the OpenSSL.podspec file does indeed exist at that URL. So what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: try adding up in podfile as pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', '~> 1.0.1.16' and update the podfile... Openssl gets integrated..

Answer (score 1):

Its changed. Use following:

**Installation**

pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'

**Or always latest version**

pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', :git => 'https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL.git', :branch => :master

Source Link: https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenSSL-Universal